# Make Android WebView can Resume latest page

Tags: android

hello im newbie in android and java development, im already make a webview app for android.

the problem when tap Android Home its close the app without resume last page when i open it again. its loading the main page, not the last page.

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPdkA.png

its like destroy my app, how to make when i touch my App its resume the latest page? maybe without loading page again?

MainActivity.java

```
package net.asiabattle.asiabattle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.net.URI;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_asiabattle);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://beta.html5test.com/");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("beta.html5test.com")) {
                return false;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml and ActivityMain.xml here http://pastebin.com/UsR3Pn5T

My last page should

> html5test .com/about.html

but when i open the app its go to home again

> html5test .com/

Comment: you mean the last page ?

Comment: ya when i touch myapp its resume the last page i visit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use Caching in android webview. If you want to resume the last page visitted, 
enable caching and in your onPause method of the activity, you can save the url of the last page . and then in your onResume method, load the url from the cache.

To load url from cache,

```
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
webview.loadUrl(weblink);
```

eg:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
         String url = webView.getUrl();
           Bundle out = new Bundle();
            webView.saveState(out);
            out.putString("url", url);
            //save the bundle to shared prefrence
            saveToPreferences(out);

    }


     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_asiabattle);
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    if(savedInstanceSate!)=null{
                webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
            webView.loadUrl(getPrefrenceBundle().getString("url"));
      }else{
    ..............
    }
    }

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.Resume();

    }
```

you can achieve the same using the functions onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState(). for more details on it [refer.](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/preserving-the-state-of-an-android-webview-on-screen-orientation-change/)

Comment: where is the onPause() and onResume() methods?

Comment: could u gimme more example? how to do that methods